# Unable to connect to the remote server when get json data Windows 8.1 App

Tags: c#, json, web-services, windows-store-apps

I try to get some json data from windows 8.1 app by using this method:

```
  public async Task<string> Get(string Url)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
            HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse;
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {

                //Need to return this response 
                string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
                return strContent;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

I got this exception: 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ServerIP:80

Although I use the same code at Windows 10 UMP App but no errors and I get my data.

What is the problem with Windows 8.1 Apps, please?

Comment: Are the windows 8.1 and windows 10 machines on the same network?  Looks simply like a networking issue to me.

Comment: The two apps are at the same machine which is windows 10 and the same network

Comment: Are you sure the URL is the same for both apps?

Comment: Yes, Same.
I take it also from nonworking solution and paste it at browser, it returns values. 
That is what makes me crazy :D

Comment: I didn't encounter your issue with your code in my Win8.1 project, could you use [Fiddle](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to debug the two projects' web traffic? Compare the differences between the two projects and analyze the reasons.